# Anonymous class how to pass local parameter?

Tags: java, java-8, vaadin, anonymous-function

I create a `StreamResource` in Vaadin. How can i pass the parameter `fileName` into the anonymous class? I have to set the `fileName` in the inner class.

Here's the source code:

```
String fileName;

public void anotherMethod(){
    StreamResource myResource = createResource();
    fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(myResource);
}

private StreamResource createResource() {
    return new StreamResource(new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
            ....
            //some magic with the filename here
        }
    }, fileName);
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException` by `fileName`.

Comment: I don't see what a lambda expression has to do with the rest of the question - and it's very unclear what you mean by "I get a NullPointerException by fileName." You also haven't shown anywhere that you're *setting* `fileName`. (It's not a parameter - it's a field.) Please provide a [mcve] and a really clear description of the problem.

Comment: it was two question, i removed the another part with the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the variable `fileName` is not initialized or you didn't provide this piece of code. Try initializing it like:

`String fileName = "some file name";` like:

```
String fileName = "virus.bat";

public void anotherMethod(){
       StreamResource myResource = createResource();
        fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(myResource);
}
private StreamResource createResource() {
    final String URL = "someURL";

    return new StreamResource(new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
              // USE THE URL.
        }
    }, fileName);
}
```

You don't pass the parameter to the anonymous class but to the `StreamResource` constructor which has two parameters: a `StreamSource` and a `String`.

I'm 100% sure you didn't assign anything to the `fileName` and the anonymous class has nothing to do with it! :)

Next time provide more code, at least with all the use-cases of presented variables so it'll be easier to help.

Comment: It doesn't need to be final if it's a field. Effectively, it's the `this` reference that's final. I think you've tried to answer this question before it's sufficiently clear in itself... I would try to avoid doing so.

Comment: In this case, he passed the `fileName` to the `StreamResource` constructor, not to the anonymous class directly, so he doesn't need the final modifier. Also, the question is wrong, cause the user asked about an anonymous class and there's no anonymous class pass in his example.

Comment: i have to set the fileName inner the getStream() method

Comment: Did you initialize it somewhere? Assigned a value to it? You shouldn't do it in `getStream();` You should do it in the class you've posted. Edit your code and show us the entire class.

Comment: @Spectre: Well, there *is* an anonymous class in the example, but as you say, it doesn't use `fileName`. Basically the question is too unclear to answer at the moment.